# Enhanced DynamicQuery?

Tags: c#, dynamicquery

I've recently started using the [DynamicQuery API](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), and it quickly became apparent that it has numerous limitations. I've found at least one improvement online: [support for enum arguments](http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2008/12/15/case-insensitive-string-comparisons-with-linq-dynamic-query/), but it's pretty clear that this API is not actively maintained (if at all).

In case I'm wrong and there *is* somebody maintaining an improved version - please post a link!

Alternatively, a separate, active project with similar goals would also be of interest.

(**Clarification**: I'm looking to parse *strings* at runtime.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what limitations are you running into?

Comment: One such limitation is mentioned in the linked article - can't pass StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase to StartsWith(). There were a couple of other minor things - e.g. the absense of the ?? operator. On the whole it's outright impressive though - it goes a long way as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end we just implemented some of the features we missed by editing the source code. Added support for passing in a static class as an "external" (DynamicQuery's terminology), support for calling methods on this static class, and type inference if any such methods are generic.

I suspect there isn't much demand for this, so I didn't bother making it available anywhere. Let me know if you think otherwise.

**Edit**: due to a request, [DynamicQuery Enhanced](http://bitbucket.org/dynamicquery/dynamicqueryenhanced) is now available on BitBucket. Expect to be underwhelmed; take a look at this [Info](http://bitbucket.org/dynamicquery/dynamicqueryenhanced/wiki/Home) and this [list of tweaks](http://bitbucket.org/dynamicquery/dynamicqueryenhanced/wiki/Tweaks).

Comment: @[Richard Hein] - alright, it's now on BitBucket at http://bitbucket.org/dynamicquery/dynamicqueryenhanced/ (full list of tweaks at http://bitbucket.org/dynamicquery/dynamicqueryenhanced/wiki/Tweaks ). Expect to be underwhelmed though :) It's old and has not been maintained up-to-date with more recent "official" releases of DynamicQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) before mentioned (here on Stackoverflow) as an alternative. I've not used it though, but it might be useful to you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not an alternative - it doesn't parse strings. It can probably be used to do more things with DynamicQuery though.

Comment: I guess it depends what you want to do. I included as an answer as it does create dynamic queries- and is very useful when you wish to build or statements. Perhaps you should update your question to state that you don't wish to utilize compile time checking?

Comment: Compile-time checking and runtime parsing are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Josh you are absolutely right. I was going to point this out but I decided not to bother.